# Google maps engine Lite API script failing

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, google-maps-engine

The code is as follows:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.whitemetro.typeandcache.TypeandCache"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=visualization&sensor=false">
    </script>
var layer = new google.maps.visualization.MapsEngineLayer(Original Type and Caches);
var layer = new google.maps.visualization.MapsEngineLayer(Basic Type And Caches);
var layer = new google.maps.visualization.MapsEngineLayer(Type And Cache-Geocache Hybrids);
```

It returns errors like this:

```
The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
```

Unexpected text found in layout file:

```
"var layer = new google.maps.visualization.MapsEngineLayer(Original Type and Caches);var layer = ne..."
```

Sorry if I am not literate with android as I have just started with it

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you're embedding HTML / JavaScript code from the [JavaScript Maps Engine Layer API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mapsenginelayers) example into an Android layout.  They are different languages & platforms and therefore cannot be mixed.

In order to embed a Maps Engine map into a mobile app, you need to be using the [platform edition of Maps Engine](https://support.google.com/mapsengine/answer/3342103?hl=en), not the Lite or Pro editions.  There is a Maps Engine Layer for Android available for enterprise (paid) customers, or if you're using the free edition you can use the [API](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/) to query your table data and use the standard Android Maps v2 API to render it.